# Is Czeck lannguage an Available language in TWIML message?

Tags: twilio-twiml

```
<Say voice="alice" language="cs-CZ">?
```

Comment: I tried: <Say voice="alice" language="cs-CZ">

Answer (score 0):

No, neither the default voice or the alice voice supports Czech, as [you can see in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say#attributes-manwoman). You can also use Amazon Polly voices, [the available languages are listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#polly-standard-and-neural-voices), but Polly does not support Czech either.